# Getting v-text-field value with xpath in Vuejs (with nightwatch)

Tags: xpath, vue.js

VueJS markup:

```
<v-menu
 lazy
 :close-on-content-click="false"
 v-model="modal"
 transition="scale-transition"
 offset-y
 full-width
 :nudge-right="40"
 max-width="290px"
 min-width="290px">

    <v-text-field
     slot="activator"
     label="Issue Date"
     v-model="date"
     append-icon="event"
     readonly
     >
    </v-text-field>
    <v-date-picker v-model="date" no-title scrollable actions>
        <template scope="{ save, cancel }">
            <v-card-actions>
                <v-spacer></v-spacer>
                <v-btn flat color="primary" @click="cancel">Cancel</v-btn>
                <v-btn flat color="primary" @click="save">OK</v-btn>
            </v-card-actions>
       </template>
   </v-date-picker>
</v-menu>
```

HTML:

```
`<div class="menu__activator">
   <div data-v-386ef34c="" class="input-group input-group--dirty input-group--append-icon input-group--text-field">
      <label>Issue Date</label>
      <div class="input-group__input">
         <input readonly="readonly" tabindex="0" aria-label="Issue Date" type="text">
         <i aria-hidden="true" class="material-icons icon input-group__append-icon input-group__icon-cb">event</i>
      </div>
      <div class="input-group__details">
         <div class="input-group__messages"></div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>`
```

How it appears in browser:

[image: Date text field and calendar]

I'd like to write e2e to assert some logic with the calendar date. Date is produced with moment to match current day. However I cannot figure out how to access that text value with xpath.

Xpath to get the element:
`$x('//div[contains(@class, "input-group--text-field")]//input[@readonly]')`

How the element appears in developer console:

[image]

With the attribute I need at the very bottom:

[image]

Xpaths I've tried which result in empty array:

```
$x('//div[contains(@class, "input-group--text-field")]//input[@readonly]//@value')


$x('//div[contains(@class, "input-group--text-field")]//input[@readonly]/@value')


$x('//div[contains(@class, "input-group--text-field")]//input[@readonly][0]//@value')
```

Edit:
Managed to get the value in chrome console:

`$x('//div[contains(@class, "input-group--text-field")]//input[@aria-label="Issue Date"]')[0].value`

But still struggling with Nightwatch

Any solutions with xpath or css are welcome! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to import chai, but this finally worked:

```
  .getValue('//div[contains(@class, "input-group--text-field")]//input[@aria-label="Issue Date"]', function(result) {
    expect(result.value).to.equal('2017-10-17')
  })
```